# Walking animation loop

Tags: python, animation, pygame

I've created a dragon that moves towards the player, and while doing so it has an animation where it flies. However, if the player stands at certain angles to the dragon, the flying animation stops until it is either directly above/to the side of the player, or immediately diagonal.

For example, standing below the dragon will trigger the animation, but standing below and over to the right will cause the dragons animation to pause until it is immediately diagonal. Here is a fully runnable example;

## Main game

```
from Rooms import *
from Player import *
import pygame


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)


pygame.init()

screen_width = 1080
screen_height = 607
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

pygame.display.set_caption('Labyrinth')

block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

rooms = []

room = Room0()
rooms.append(room)

current_room_no = 0
current_room = rooms[current_room_no]

player = Player("Isaac.png", 420, 150, current_room)
all_sprites_list.add(player)


clock = pygame.time.Clock()


done = False


# -- MAIN PROGRAM LOOP -- #

# -- Event processing --

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True


# Player controls

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-7, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(7, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, -7)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, 7)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(7, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-7, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, 7)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, -7)

# -- Game Logic --

    all_sprites_list.update()
    current_room.enemy_sprites.update(player)

# Hit detection 

    screen.blit(current_room.background_image, current_room.background_position)

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    current_room.enemy_sprites.draw(screen)


    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

## Dragon class

```
import pygame
import math
from Player import Player
import time

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

class SpriteSheet(object):

    def __init__(self, file_name):

        self.sprite_sheet = pygame.image.load(file_name).convert()


    def get_image(self, x, y, width, height):

        image = pygame.Surface([width, height]).convert()
        image.blit(self.sprite_sheet, (0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
        image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        return image


class Dragon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        super().__init__()

        self.flying_frames_l = []
        self.flying_frames_r = []

        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("Dragon.png")

# Flying left
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(12, 22, 95, 85)
        self.flying_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(140, 35, 95, 67)
        self.flying_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(18, 138, 96, 55)
        self.flying_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(128, 131, 96, 63)
        self.flying_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(140, 35, 95, 67)
        self.flying_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(12, 22, 95, 85)
        self.flying_frames_l.append(image)

# Flying right
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(12, 22, 95, 85)
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
        self.flying_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(140, 35, 95, 67)
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
        self.flying_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(18, 138, 96, 55)
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
        self.flying_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(128, 131, 96, 63)
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
        self.flying_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(140, 35, 95, 67)
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
        self.flying_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(12, 22, 95, 85)
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
        self.flying_frames_r.append(image)


        self.image = self.flying_frames_r[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

        self.health = 100


    def update(self, player):

        posx = self.rect.x
        posy = self.rect.y

        dx = self.rect.x - player.rect.x
        dy = self.rect.y - player.rect.y

        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)

        dx = dx / dist
        dy = dy / dist

        if dx > 0:
            self.speedx = -1.5

        if dx <= 0:
            self.speedx = -1.5          

        if dy >= 0:
            self.speedy = -1.5

        if dy <= 0:
            self.speedy = -1.5


        self.rect.x += dx * self.speedx
        self.rect.y += dy * self.speedy


        if self.rect.x < player.rect.x:
            frame = (posx // 10) % len(self.flying_frames_l)
            self.image = self.flying_frames_l[frame]
        else:
            frame = (posx // 10) % len(self.flying_frames_r)
            self.image = self.flying_frames_r[frame]

        if self.rect.y < player.rect.y:
            frame = (posy // 10) % len(self.flying_frames_l)
            self.image = self.flying_frames_l[frame]
        else:
            frame = (posy // 10) % len(self.flying_frames_r)
            self.image = self.flying_frames_r[frame]
```

## Player class

```
import pygame


BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    def __init__(self, filename, x, y, current_room):

        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y
```

## Room class

```
import Player
import pygame
from Enemies import Dragon


class Room(object):
    enemy_sprites = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.enemy_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()


class Room0(Room):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        enemy = Dragon(380, 280)
        self.enemy_sprites.add(enemy)

        self.background_position = [0, 0]
        self.background_image = pygame.image.load("Floor.png").convert()
```

[image]

This is the spritesheet im using to make it easier to run the code

Comment: Is that an error in the program? isn't it `ZeroDivisionError`?

Comment: Oh yes sorry, it doesn’t occur in the full code due to the collision detection I just forgot to account for that in the sample code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the `ZeroDivisionError` Azhy already pointed out, your problem is that you calculate the current image of the animation by diving `posx`/`posy` by a constant.

So if `posy` does not change, the image will not change.

You can print out `frame` at the end of `update` to see it yourself.

---

You could extract handling the animation into its own class or something, here's a simple example:

```
class Animation(object):
    def __init__(self, sprite, speed, images):
        self.sprite = sprite
        self.images = images
        self.speed = speed
        self.step = 0
        self.frame = 0

    def update(self):
        self.step += 1
        if self.step >= self.speed:
            self.frame = (self.frame + 1) % len(self.images)
            self.sprite.image = self.images[self.frame]
            self.step = 0
```

and then the `Dragon` class could look like this:

```
class Dragon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y):

        super().__init__()

        flying_frames_l = []
        flying_frames_r = []

        sprite_sheet = SpriteSheet("Dragon.png")

# Flying left
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(12, 22, 95, 85)
        flying_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(140, 35, 95, 67)
        flying_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(18, 138, 96, 55)
        flying_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(128, 131, 96, 63)
        flying_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(140, 35, 95, 67)
        flying_frames_l.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(12, 22, 95, 85)
        flying_frames_l.append(image)
        self.flying_left = Animation(self, 6, flying_frames_l)

# Flying right
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(12, 22, 95, 85)
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
        flying_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(140, 35, 95, 67)
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
        flying_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(18, 138, 96, 55)
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
        flying_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(128, 131, 96, 63)
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
        flying_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(140, 35, 95, 67)
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
        flying_frames_r.append(image)
        image = sprite_sheet.get_image(12, 22, 95, 85)
        image = pygame.transform.flip(image, True, False)
        flying_frames_r.append(image)
        self.flying_right = Animation(self, 6, flying_frames_r)

        self.image = flying_frames_r[0]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.x = x

        self.speedx = 0
        self.speedy = 0

        self.health = 100
        self.animation = self.flying_right

    def update(self, player):

        posx = self.rect.x
        posy = self.rect.y

        dx = self.rect.x - player.rect.x
        dy = self.rect.y - player.rect.y

        dist = math.hypot(dx, dy)

        if dist > 0:
            dx = dx / dist
            dy = dy / dist

        if dx > 0:
            self.speedx = -1.5
            self.animation = self.flying_left

        if dx <= 0:
            self.speedx = -1.5          
            self.animation = self.flying_right

        if dy >= 0:
            self.speedy = -1.5

        if dy <= 0:
            self.speedy = -1.5


        self.rect.x += dx * self.speedx
        self.rect.y += dy * self.speedy


        self.animation.update()
```

Note how we simply increase a counter to see if we should change the image instead on relying on the current position.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, thanks so much for your help!